# Pygame - Alinhar tela no centro

Tags: python

Gente voces tem conhecimento de como alinhar a tela do meu jogo no centro da tela do desktop?

Comment: Você tem o código que gera sua janela? Fica mais fácil de receber respostas.

Comment: Você tem que colocar mais informações em sua pergunta. Como saber o que alinhar sem ver o código? Colocar imagens também ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**SDL**, engine que o **Pygame** é baseado, usa a variável de ambiente **SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED** para indicar que a janela deve ser centralizada. A variável deve ser declarada antes do **Pygame** ser iniciado pela função **init()**.

```
import pygame
import os 
os.environ['SDL_VIDEO_CENTERED'] = '1'
pygame.init()
```